# Sudden 100% Wide in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm implementing a large project with Bootstrap 3, and today I saw that suddenly the site is on 100% width. Because of the cache of the browser, it happened yesterday, but I only saw it today, so I don't know what piece of code I was working on that triggered it. I don't recall messing with variables, grid.less or any file that traditionally may have something to do with the width of the site.

Being so, I'm kinda lost! Where would you suggest that I look? I disabled custom CSS files one by one, and nothing...

I cannot send link as I'm working on virtual machine, I'm attaching the code from the main layout file, just in case.

```
<?php echo $this->docType().PHP_EOL;?>
<html lang="<?php echo Inwx_Website::getLanguage();?>">
<head>
<?php
echo $this->headMeta().PHP_EOL;
echo $this->headTitle().PHP_EOL;
echo $this->headLink().PHP_EOL;
echo $this->headStyle();
?>
</head>

<body ng-app="inwxApp">
<div class="viewport">
<div class="frame">
<div class="view" ng-controller="FrontCtrl">
<div id="ajax-loading">
<img src="/img/ajax-loader.gif" class="ajax-loader"/>
</div>
<!--Nav Top Blue-->
<div>
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<a class="pull-left" href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'index'),'default',true);?>" target="_top">
<img src="/img/logo-inwx.png" alt="InterNetworx" title="InterNetworx"/>
</a>
<div class="row col-md-3 pull-right">
<div class="pull-right">
<?php echo $this->drawLanguages();?> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-8 pull-right ix-login" ng-show="loggedin==0" ng-cloak>
<ul class="pull-right">
<li><a href="" class="ix-login-buttons ix-popover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom"><?php echo _t("Login")?></a></li>
<li><a class="ix-login-buttons" href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'customer','action'=>'signup'),'default');?>"><?php echo _t("Register")?></a></li>
</ul>
<form id="main-loginform" ng-submit="login('main-loginform')">
<input class="col-md-2" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo _t('Username')?>" ng-model="username" name="username" value="">
<input class="col-md-2" type="password" placeholder="<?php echo _t('Password')?>" ng-model="password" name="password" value="">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success"><?php echo _t("Login")?></button>
<a href="#modal-forgotten-password" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="small"><?php echo _t("Forgot your password?")?></a>
</form>
</div>

<!-- logged in: user -->
<div class="ix-info-costumer pull-right" ng-show="loggedin==1" ng-cloak>
<ul class="ix-down">
<li><?php echo _t('Username')?>: {{userData.firstname}} {{userData.lastname}}</li>
<li><?php echo _t('Credit balance')?>: {{creditData.available | currency: '€'}}</li>
<li><?php echo _t('Customer id')?>: {{userData.customerId}}</li>
<li><?php echo _t('Service PIN')?>: {{userData.servicePin}}</li>
<li><a href="#" ng-click="logout()"><?php echo _t('Logout')?></a>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div><!--/Nav Top Blue-->

<!--Nav Grey-->
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top ">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ng-include src="'<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'navi'),'default',true);?>'"></ng-include>
<div class="pull-right" ng-show="cartData.list.length">
<!-- shopping cart info -->
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm ix-btn-custom" data-placement="bottom"><img src="/img/shopping-icon.png" />{{cartData.list.length}}</a>
<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display:none">
<div class="row ix-shop-popover">
<div class="pull-left">
<ul class="ix-shop-popover">
<li>{{cartData.list.length}} <?php echo _t("Items")?></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
<ul class="ix-shop-popover">
<li>{{cartData.totalPrice | currency: '€'}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ix-divider">
<div class="pull-left">
<a href="#" class="ix-white"><?php echo _t("Empty cart")?></a>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'cart','action'=>'index'),'default');?>" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-xs"><?php echo _t("Check Out")?></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div> <!--/Nav Grey-->


</div> <!-- end of InitCtrl -->
<!--Content-->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<!--Domain Search Static in all pages-->
<div class="col-md-6">
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<?php echo _t("DOMAIN CHECK")?>: 
</div>
<div class="form-group pull-right">
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'domain','action'=>'check'),'default');?>" ng-click="triggerCheck()" class="btn btn-default btn-success"> <i class="icon-white icon-search"></i> <?php echo _t("Search")?></a>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-7 pull-right">
<div class="input-group">
<label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2"><?php echo _t('My Domain'); ?></label>

<input placeholder="<?php echo _t('My Domain'); ?>" type="text" ng-model="domain" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2">

<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<?php echo _t("Default")?>
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#"><?php echo _t("Generic")?></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><?php echo _t("America")?></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><?php echo _t("Europe")?></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><?php echo _t("Asia")?></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><?php echo _t("Africa")?></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><?php echo _t("Oceania")?></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><?php echo _t("All")?></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><?php echo _t("New TDLs")?></a></li>
</ul>
</span>
</div>    
</div>


</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<!--/Domain Search Static in all pages-->
<?php echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setSeparator("/"); ?>
<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
</div>
</div>    
</div>
</div>
</div>            
<?php
echo $this->headScript().PHP_EOL;
echo $this->inlineScript().PHP_EOL;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pop open firebug and inspect the body tag to see if what stylesheet the width 100% is coming from.  Bootstrap 3 is very focused on responsive layouts so this would make sense.

If it is a new site, it will have a 100% width as it exist in a block level html tag that will not have a width constraint until you give one.  I dont see any bootstrap class names to enforce a width either.

As a developer you should have you cache turned off almost always :)  Most browser web dev toolbars provide this as an option.

Hope that gives you a starting point.  Discovering the source of width should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Your comment definitely helped. For whatever reason the variables were not calculating properly the width and where leaving the container{ } empty. I filled it manually and it was solved. Thanks!